# is it possible to install multiple copies of a homebrew formula?

Tags: homebrew

I would like to install two copies of the same formula using homebrew:

```
$ brew install gromacs --with-x
```

succeeds in installing the single precision binaries.  But then, when I try to install the double precision binaries, it fails with the following message:

```
$ brew install gromacs --with-x --enable-double
Warning: gromacs-4.6.3 already installed
```

Is there a way to get both the single precision and double precision copies of gromacs?  Thanks.